# Bitlocker and virtualbox 64bit

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, 64-bit, bitlocker

I have a new laptop in which i activated BitLocker without having a TPM chip. 
Prior to doing that I installed virtualbox and enabled VMM(?) in bios, I dont remember the exact name of it but it was something I had to do to enable my machine to allow 64bit virtualized systems.
After i enabled BitLocker I no longer have the possibility to select 64 bit os's in VirtualBox.

My Setup:

Windows 8.1 pro
Lenovo Yoga Pro 2, 64 bit.

Am I missing something fundamental?

I have doublechecked that my bios settings are the correct ones for enabling hardware support for virtualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out I had activated Hyper-V also. Since Hyper-V is running as a service it will block the OS access to the hardware accelleration thus disabling the abilitiy for virtualbox to run 64bit systems.